# Why do we need to use std::vector::pointer to access elements?

Tags: c++, stl

Usually we could use vector array accessor to access the element and modify the element, why do we need the pointer?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e4tx21z(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Dyrandz I don't think they are same question, I guess Adam is asking why there is a seemingly redundant `pointer` type in `std::vector` while elements can be always accessed via other accessors such as `operator[]`

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the convenience `typedef` named `pointer` in `std::vector` is no different from the presence of the myriad other `typedef`s like `value_type`, `reference`, `allocator_type`, `size_type`... You can find the full list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). These aliases are very useful in generic settings. Lets say you are writing a generic function which accepts some containers and would like to create an instance of type `T*` where the container contains objects of type `T`. For the `std::vector`(generic type `V`, say) specialization(may apply to a bunch of other STL containers as well), you could get this type as `typename V::value_type *` or more simply as `typename V::pointer`.

Answer (score -1):

If you think `pointer` type in `std::vector` is unnecessary, I'd say it's not.

`vector` can be treated as a managed, dynamically-sized array, it does support all meaningful operations which arrays can do, even it has compatible memory layout and can be used as an array in many cases.

If you can access element in array via pointer, it should be doable in `vector`, too.

The `pointer` type is the simplification of `T *` as `vector` is a template.